# Batch Process images to remove identifying features

Tags: software-recommendation, batch-processing

I'm looking for some software that can batch process images to remove any identifying features (the same effect as saving a screen shot of the image). I don't want any data associated with the image to remain so that it appears to be a new image to search engines. Is there a program that can do that?

Comment: identifying features, you mean date of creation / EXIF?

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to batch this for other image files you can use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#strip) to remove exif data by using:

```
convert <input file> -strip <output file>
```

Per the source it says:

> strip the image of any profiles, comments or these PNG chunks:
>   bKGD,cHRM,EXIF,gAMA,iCCP,iTXt,sRGB,tEXt,zCCP,zTXt,date.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are for web or digital usage (I mean RGB 72dpi) you can use Photoshop "save for web" with the option "Metadata: None". It will produce a simple image with no data added (this is to optimize the size).

You can make a batch and save in this way thousands of images automatically.

This will not work if you need CMYK or images that are bigger than a certain size ("save for web" will still work for images up to 5000x5000 pixels), unless you make a second batch to re-save in CMYK 300 dpi or whatever you need. But it is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks Mario. I found a free program called Batch Purifier Lite which strips metatags. Would something like that do as good a job or should I be using Photoshop?

Comment: @cxzaqwer I'm sorry but I don't know that software so I can't say if it will work well or not. I knew of a Gimp plugin that maybe will do what you need but I never used it: http://registry.gimp.org/node/157